# Treectrl wxpython

Tags: wxpython

Im trying to create a tree ctrl component within my panel but when I run the code, I don't see any action.

code

```
import wx

class MyTreeCtrl(wx.TreeCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style):
        wx.TreeCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style)



class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
        size=(700, 700))
        tID = wx.NewId()
        self.tree = MyTreeCtrl(self,tId,wx.DefaultPosition,wx.DefaultSize,wx.TR_DEFAULT_SIZE)
        isz = (16,16)
        il = wx.ImageList(isz[0], isz[1])
        fldridx     = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_FOLDER,      wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fldropenidx = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN,   wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fileidx     = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_NORMAL_FILE, wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        smileidx    = il.Add(images.Smiles.GetBitmap())

        self.tree.SetImageList(il)
        self.il = il

        # NOTE:  For some reason tree items have to have a data object in
        #        order to be sorted.  Since our compare just uses the labels
        #        we don't need any real data, so we'll just use None below for
        #        the item data.

        self.root = self.tree.AddRoot("The Root Item")
        self.tree.SetPyData(self.root, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)


        for x in range(15):
            child = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Item %d" % x)
            self.tree.SetPyData(child, None)
            self.tree.SetItemImage(child, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
            self.tree.SetItemImage(child, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)

            for y in range(5):
                last = self.tree.AppendItem(child, "item %d-%s" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y)))
                self.tree.SetPyData(last, None)
                self.tree.SetItemImage(last, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
                self.tree.SetItemImage(last, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)

                for z in range(5):
                    item = self.tree.AppendItem(last,  "item %d-%s-%d" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y), z))
                    self.tree.SetPyData(item, None)
                    self.tree.SetItemImage(item, fileidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
                    self.tree.SetItemImage(item, smileidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Selected)

        print self.tree
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show() 


    def InitUI(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        #midPan = wx.Panel(panel)
        #midPan.SetBackgroundColour('#ededed')

        vbox.Add(self.tree, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.App()
        Example(None,title="Border")
        app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I can see why. The code is unrunnable in its current form. The "tId" is an undefined variable and wx.TR_DEFAULT_SIZE is not a real style flag. Also you make reference to the "images" module but you don't import it. Having a runnable example would be nice.

You aren't really asking a question either. What isn't working? When I edit the code to get it to run, I end up with this:

```
import wx

class MyTreeCtrl(wx.TreeCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style):
        wx.TreeCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style)



class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
        size=(700, 700))
        tID = wx.NewId()
        self.tree = MyTreeCtrl(self,tID,wx.DefaultPosition,wx.DefaultSize,wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS)
        isz = (16,16)
        il = wx.ImageList(isz[0], isz[1])
        fldridx     = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_FOLDER,      wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fldropenidx = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN,   wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fileidx     = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_NORMAL_FILE, wx.ART_OTHER, isz))


        self.tree.SetImageList(il)
        self.il = il

        # NOTE:  For some reason tree items have to have a data object in
        #        order to be sorted.  Since our compare just uses the labels
        #        we don't need any real data, so we'll just use None below for
        #        the item data.

        self.root = self.tree.AddRoot("The Root Item")
        self.tree.SetPyData(self.root, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)


        for x in range(15):
            child = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Item %d" % x)
            self.tree.SetPyData(child, None)
            self.tree.SetItemImage(child, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
            self.tree.SetItemImage(child, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)

            for y in range(5):
                last = self.tree.AppendItem(child, "item %d-%s" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y)))
                self.tree.SetPyData(last, None)
                self.tree.SetItemImage(last, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
                self.tree.SetItemImage(last, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)

                for z in range(5):
                    item = self.tree.AppendItem(last,  "item %d-%s-%d" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y), z))
                    self.tree.SetPyData(item, None)
                    self.tree.SetItemImage(item, fileidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
                    #self.tree.SetItemImage(item, smileidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Selected)

        print self.tree
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show() 


    def InitUI(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        #midPan = wx.Panel(panel)
        #midPan.SetBackgroundColour('#ededed')

        vbox.Add(self.tree, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.App()
        Example(None,title="Border")
        app.MainLoop()
```

This creates the tree control as a small box in the upper left corner. The next issue is that you are stacking the panel on top of the treectrl since you gave both widgets the frame as their parent and you created the treectrl first. I rearranged your code a bit to make the panel the treectrl's parent. See below:

```
import wx

class MyTreeCtrl(wx.TreeCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style):
        wx.TreeCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style)



class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(700, 700))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        tID = wx.NewId()
        self.tree = MyTreeCtrl(panel,tID,wx.DefaultPosition,wx.DefaultSize,wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS)
        vbox.Add(self.tree, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)

        isz = (16,16)
        il = wx.ImageList(isz[0], isz[1])
        fldridx     = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_FOLDER,      wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fldropenidx = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN,   wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fileidx     = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_NORMAL_FILE, wx.ART_OTHER, isz))


        self.tree.SetImageList(il)
        self.il = il

        # NOTE:  For some reason tree items have to have a data object in
        #        order to be sorted.  Since our compare just uses the labels
        #        we don't need any real data, so we'll just use None below for
        #        the item data.

        self.root = self.tree.AddRoot("The Root Item")
        self.tree.SetPyData(self.root, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)


        for x in range(15):
            child = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Item %d" % x)
            self.tree.SetPyData(child, None)
            self.tree.SetItemImage(child, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
            self.tree.SetItemImage(child, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)

            for y in range(5):
                last = self.tree.AppendItem(child, "item %d-%s" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y)))
                self.tree.SetPyData(last, None)
                self.tree.SetItemImage(last, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
                self.tree.SetItemImage(last, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)

                for z in range(5):
                    item = self.tree.AppendItem(last,  "item %d-%s-%d" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y), z))
                    self.tree.SetPyData(item, None)
                    self.tree.SetItemImage(item, fileidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
                    #self.tree.SetItemImage(item, smileidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Selected)

        print self.tree
        self.Centre()
        self.Show() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.App()
        Example(None,title="Border")
        app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: thanks much Driscoll..One more question.How do I know the list of parameters that needs to be passed for initialization of a Panel..For example:- dir(wx.Panel) gives me all the methods but how do I know the list of parameters for a particular method.

Comment: For info try `help(wx.Panel)`